# SwiftUI - Picker in a list with the list Style(.grouped) value disrupts the text on the Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

In a SwiftUI List with the `.grouped` list style, a Picker embedded within a DisclosureGroup can cause layout issues when the Picker's text becomes too long, causing it to extend beyond the frame.

Here's the code for the Picker and the List:

```swift
@ViewBuilder var categoryPicker: some View {
    Picker("Category", selection: $icon) {
        ForEach(category, id: \.self) { category in
            Text(category)
                .tag(category)
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    List {
        Section("Category") {
            DisclosureGroup("Create a category",
                            isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                categoryNameTextField
                categoryPicker
                saveButton
            }
        }
        
        Section("Created category") {
            createdCategoryList
        }
    }
    .listStyle(.grouped)
}
```

[image: Obraz1]
[image: Obraz2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the full name of a category, you can truncate it to a sensible size for making the item label. The `tag` of each item should still be the full name.

For example:

```swift
private func sensiblePickerText(category: String) -> String {
    category.count < 30 ? category : category.prefix(30) + "..."
}

@ViewBuilder var categoryPicker: some View {
    Picker("Category", selection: $icon) {
        ForEach(category, id: \.self) { category in
            Text(sensiblePickerText(category: category))
                .tag(category)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picker]

Comment: I also use Text(category.prefix(75)), but your solution is better. Do you think this is a bug in SwiftUI?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! It would be a bug if the documentation would describe it as behaving in a different way. But I don't suppose there is any description of how it is expected to behave when the strings are excessively long. Still, you could submit feedback to Apple if you think it's worth pursuing.

Comment: Ps. You could make the function a lot more sophisticated, such as only breaking on full words or allowing some leniency around the threshold length. Be sure to test edge cases too, I realised that the example I provided doesn't handle a length of exactly 30 chars properly.